# Is there a noticeable increase in computer performance moving from a Dual Core to an i5?

Tags: performance, cpu, intel-core-i5, cpu-speed, dual-core

I have an i5-3470 3.2Ghz and 6GB or RAM.  I also have a Dual Core E5700 3.0 and 8GB or RAM.  Both use Windows 7 Pro.  I am currently using the latter.  I would like to use the i5, but as a developer, it is a hassle unless I'm going to see a really big speed difference.  Not for games.  For work.

Is there any difference I can detect with the human eye?  I don't care about a benchmark, if I have to have a computer to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The i5-3470 has more than five times the overall performance of the E5700 and about three times the single-thread performance. The difference would be impossible to miss.